# Scala's for comprehension for Futures and Options

Tags: scala, playframework

I have recently read Manuel Bernhardt's new book [Reactive Web Applications](https://manning.com/books/reactive-web-applications). In his book, he states that Scala developers should **never** use `.get` to retrieve an optional value.

I want to pick up his suggestions but I am struggling to avoid `.get` when using for comprehensions for Futures.

Let's say I have the following code:

```
for {
        avatarUrl <- avatarService.retrieve(email)
        user <- accountService.save(Account(profiles = List(profile.copy(avatarUrl = avatarUrl)))
        userId <- user.id
        _ <- accountTokenService.save(AccountToken.create(userId, email))
      } yield {
        Logger.info("Foo bar")
      }
```

Normally, I would have used `AccountToken.create(user.id.get, email)` instead of `AccountToken.create(userId, email)`. However, when trying to avoid this bad practice, I get the following exception:

```
[error]  found   : Option[Nothing]
[error]  required: scala.concurrent.Future[?]
[error]         userId <- user.id
[error]                ^
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: The problem with for-comprehensions is that they always require the same monad. I.e. you cannot use a for-comprehension combining an `Option` with an `Future` :(

Comment: Ah okay! Thanks for your help. Can you recommend any elegant workarounds to avoid `.get`?

Comment: Something like `userId <- user.id.map(concurrent.Future.successful(_) ).getOrElse(concurrent.Future.failed(new Exception(...)))`  may help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### First option

If you *really* want to use `for` comprehension you'll have to separate it to several `for`s, where each works with the same monad type:

```
for {
  avatarUrl <- avatarService.retrieve(email)
  user <- accountService.save(Account(profiles = List(profile.copy(avatarUrl = avatarUrl)))
} yield for {
  userId <- user.id
} yield for {
  _ <- accountTokenService.save(AccountToken.create(userId, email))
}
```

#### Second option

Another option is to avoid `Future[Option[T]]` altogether and use `Future[T]` which can materialize into `Failure(e)` where `e` is a `NoSuchElementException` whenever you expect a `None` (in your case, the `accountService.save()` method):

```
def saveWithoutOption(account: Account): Future[User] = {
  this.save(account) map { userOpt =>
    userOpt.getOrElse(throw new NoSuchElementException)
  }
}
```

Then you'll have:

```
(for {
  avatarUrl <- avatarService.retrieve(email)
  user <- accountService.saveWithoutOption(Account(profiles = List(profile.copy(avatarUrl = avatarUrl)))
  _ <- accountTokenService.save(AccountToken.create(user.id, email))
} yield {
  Logger.info("Foo bar")
}) recover {
  case t: NoSuchElementException => Logger.error("boo")
}
```

#### Third option

Fall back to `map`/`flatMap` and introduce intermediate results.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a step back and explore the meaning of our expression:

- A `Future` is "eventually a value (but might fail)"
- An `Option` is "maybe a value"

What are the semantics of `Future[Option]`?  Let's explore the values to gain some intuition:

**Future[Option]**

- `Success(Some(x))` => Good. Let's do stuff with x
- `Success(None)` => Finished but got nothing => This is probably an application-level error
- `Failure(_)` =>  Something went wrong, so we don't have a value

We can flatten `Success(None)` into a `Failure(SomeApplicationException)` and eliminate the need of handling the `Option` separately.

For that, we can define a generic function to turn an `Option` into a `Future` and use the `for-comprehension` to apply the flattening.

```
def optionToFuture[T](opt:Option[T], ex: ()=>Exception):Future[T] = opt match {
   case Some(v) => Future.successful(v)
   case None => Future.failed(ex())
  }
```

We can now express our computation fluently with a `for-comprehension`:

```
for {
  avatarUrl <- avatarService.retrieve(email)
  user <- accountService.save(Account(profiles = List(profile.copy(avatarUrl = avatarUrl)))
  userId <- optionToFuture(user.id, () => new UserNotFoundException(email))
  _ <- accountTokenService.save(AccountToken.create(userId, email))
} yield {
   Logger.info("Foo bar")
}
```

Comment: I like that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Stop `Option` propogation by failing the Future when option is None**

Fail the future when id is none and abort

```
for {
....
accountOpt <-
  user.id.map { id =>
    Account.create(id, ...)
  }.getOrElse {
   Future.failed(new Exception("could not create account."))
  }

...
} yield result
```

Better to have a custom exception like

```
case class NoIdException(msg: String) extends Exception(msg)
```

invoking `.get` on Option should be done only if you are sure that option is `Some(x)` otherwise `.get` will throw an exception.

Thats by using `.get` is not good practise because it may cause an exception in the code.

Instead of `.get` its good practice to use `getOrElse`.

You can `map` or `flatMap` the option to get access to the inner value.

**Good practice**

```
val x: Option[Int] = giveMeOption()
x.getOrElse(defaultValue)
```

**Get can be used here**

```
val x: Option[Int] = giveMeOption()
x.OrElse(Some(1)).get
```

Comment: Thanks but I know this already. I think your answer does not address my question...

Comment: @JohnDoe  .. i think this will help you to get rid of option